# (PHP) random post order with specific post within first n posts?

Tags: php, random, shuffle

I'm working on a page, displaying posts in a random order with PHP's *shuffle()* function. There's one specific *title-post* which should always pop up within the first 5 posts. Could be like:

```
1. Post-7
2. Post-2
3. Post-1
4. Title-Post
5. Post-5
6. Post-4
7. Post-3
8. Post-6
```

OR

```
1. Post-2
2. Title-Post
3. Post-4
4. Post-6
5. Post-1
6. Post-3
7. Post-7
8. Post-5
```

Could someone give me a hint on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting this from a database ?. Than you can try order by rand() limit 5

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you are getting the list from a database and you have the "title-post" in another variable.

You could simply do the following :

```
$array = array('post-1', 'post-2', 'post-3'); //the array you should get from the DB
shuffle($array); //shuffle all
$title = 'Title-Post';

array_splice( $array, rand(0, 4), 0, $title); //insert the title somewhere between 0 and 4 so in the first 5 values
```

That should do the trick

EDIT : comments

Comment: Yes, this is the way I would have done it: Remove the post in question from the array, randomize the array, and then splice the post randomly somewhere in the first five locations.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(I just generate a random number between 0 and 4 and if it's not the titel post i put the post at the end and put the titel post at that position)

```
<?php

    $input = array("Post-7", "Post-2", "Post-1", "Title-Post", "Post-5", "Post-4", "Post-3", "Post-6");
    $titel = rand(0, 4);
    shuffle($input);

    if($input[$titel] != "Title-Post") {
        $input[] = $input[$titel];
        $temp = $input[array_search("Title-Post", $input)];
        unset($input[array_search("Title-Post", $input)]);
        $input[$titel] = $temp;
    }

    foreach($input as $value)
        echo $value . "<br />";

?>
```

Possible output:

```
Post-2
Post-1
Title-Post
Post-6
Post-7
Post-5
Post-3
Post-4
```